# HTML Select with ng-change doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following controller code:

```
  $scope.types = ['First', 'Second', 'Third']
  $scope.type = $scope.types[0]

  $scope.changeType = function() {
    console.log($scope.type)
  }
```

HTML code:

```
<select class="form-control" id="type" name="type" ng-change="changeType()" ng-model="type" ng-options="type for type in types" />
```

I see select, all is good, but when I try to change value in the select, I see 'First' in the console always. What's the trouble? How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: It  works for me - http://jsfiddle.net/5DMjt/2179/

Answer (score 3):

problem is with ng-model name conflicting with ng-options

```
ng-model="type" ng-options="type for type in types"
```

use something else for ng-model, maybe something like

```
ng-model="selectType" ng-options="type for type in types"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your model name is same as the selected type in the ng-option hence its creating a issue

Change

```
ng-options="type for type in types"
```

to

```
 ng-options="item for item in types"
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/p6pSivqHFcW7XLXfbg9o?p=preview

Comment: Your model name is same as the selected type in the ng-option hence its creating a issue